# Does G ever visibly assimilate in voice?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

According to Allen's *Vox Latina*, `/b/` regularly becomes voiceless before a voiceless consonant. This shows up sometimes in writing: for example, we see forms of *ob-sideō* written occasionally as *opsideō*. The same seems to be true for `/d/`, in cases where it doesn't fully assimilate.

Is this ever attested with `/g/`? That is, is there ever an instance where `/g/` is written as *c* before a voiceless consonant?

(The most obvious example would be before `/s/`, as in *reg-s*, but that has a separate letter to represent it. I don't doubt that the final consonant in *rex* was voiceless, but I'm curious specifically about cases where a scribe had a choice between voiced and voiceless letters, and went with the voiceless one.)

Comment: I once read a comment by an Italian who said it is physically impossible to pronounce "absolute" with a voiced "b" and a voiceless "s", but rather one can only say "abzolute" or "apsolute".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a third-conjugation verb, a [g] sound at the end of a present stem generally alternates with a [k] sound, written as ⟨c⟩, before the [t] of the past participle/supine suffix. I believe the phonemic representations of these sounds would usually be given as /g/ and /k/ respectively; if that is correct, this is not a case where "/g/ is written as c" but a case where the phoneme /g/ alternates with the distinct phoneme /k/. (However, whether an apparently neutralizing assimilation results in a change in phonemic identity can be a difficult theoretical question.)

No verb has a past participle/supine form that is typically written with ⟨gt⟩. (I don't know whether there are any examples of ⟨gt⟩ spellings in inscriptions.) Some verbs with present stems ending in [g] have, or may have, a past participle/supine form with something other than ⟨ct⟩ [kt], such as ⟨x⟩ [ks] (*figo, fixum*) or ⟨s⟩ [s] (*dispergo, dispersum*).

Here are some examples (vowel length not marked):

- *ago, actum*
- *cingo, cinctum*
- *fingo, fictum*
- *fligo, flictum*
- *stringo, strictum*

This alternation between ⟨g⟩ and ⟨c⟩, and the similar alternation between  ⟨b⟩ and ⟨p⟩ in verbs like *scribo, scriptum,* is presumably the result of regressive voicing assimilation. The period over which this assimilation was actively applied is not certain: it's related to the famous problem of explaining "Lachmann's law", the sound change whereby vowels in certain past participle/supine stems were lengthened (so *ago* has short *a* but *actum* has long *a*).